# xslt - find all elements with unknown namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

i have a very generic xml schema allowing any additional data - and i want to process that data with xslt.
the xsd part looks like that:

```
<xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
 <xs:annotation>
  <xs:documentation>any additional properties</xs:documentation>
 </xs:annotation>
</xs:any>
```

now i want to process that information with xslt. i thought of something like: "find every element that has an unknown namespace." is sthg like that possible? our do you have a better suggestion on how to proceed?

BR

Comment: Your question is not clear. What does "unknown namespace" mean? Unknown to whom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the parent element you can of course use

```
<xsl:template match="ns1:foo" xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/ns1">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(namespace-uri() = namespace-uri(current())]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course in most cases the `xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/ns1"` would be defined on the `xsl:stylesheet`, but to make the snippet complete I put it on the template.

Comment: seems to work so far! How would i have to write the template then, to only work for this unknown namespace? In the parent element i already have an other apply-templates and render some text...

Comment: It depends a bit on how many namespace the whole document uses, if there is a single target namespace in the schema and the root element and its children are all in the namespace then you should be able to write `<xsl:template match="*[not(namespace-uri() = namespace-uri(/*))]">...</xsl:template>`. If there are more namespaces involved then we need to see some more details of them.

Comment: there are up to 4 namespaces in the whole document. THIS specific parent element uses one of them and all its child, with exception of the generic one, use the same.

Comment: As far as I understand the `namespace="##other"` constraint on `xs:any`, it simply says that the namespaces will be different from the one of the parent respectively ancestor. Obviously if the document uses several namespaces and you need to write templates matching them, it depends on the transformation that you want to achieve. Maybe doing `<xsl:template match="ns1:foo//*[namespace-uri() != 'http://example.com/ns1']">` is a starting point. Of course using a mode is also an approach to distinguish processing steps.